# get content through API for wordpress page, built from template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to get content rendered from a wordpress page through API. Wordpress page is built from a from wordpress template code only. Only title is from blocks and thats it.

When I am fetching the page through API , I am getting this in response

```
 "content": {
            "rendered": "",
            "protected": false
        },
        "excerpt": {
            "rendered": "",
            "protected": false
```

why is `content.rendered` blank . The api url that I am using is this

```
http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=mySlug
```

How can I get content from page just as it would render on a browser. I need  to render it through react like this

```
 ...
const [pageContent, setPageContent] = useState('');
setPageContent(page.content.rendered);
...
return (
        <div>
            <h1>Search Page</h1>
            {loading ? (
                <p>Loading...</p>
            ) : (
                <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: pageContent }} />
            )}
        </div>
```

and hope that if I get content in `page.content.rendered` , it will render same way as it would do it when calling the page normally (not api). How can I achieve this?

Comment: `page.content.rendered` only includes what you actually have in the content of the post, it won't take into account any HTML that's generated from your template file

Comment: So how would I get HTML that is generated from template. I am trying to use this api - https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/pages/#schema-template , and I sent a request like this `http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?template=myTemplate` but I think it gave me all the tempolates and their metadata.  How do I get rendered html back from one template, any idea ?

Comment: You could try making a custom REST endpoint that just returns the HTML data from the template